# Get element position in index REVERSED

Tags: jquery, class, element, reverse

I've done some Googling and found some pretty complex solutions, but is there a simple way of getting jQuery to reverse an element index.

Currently

```
$('.elementClass').index(this);
```

Will give me the position of the clicked element within the class "elementClass" but I need this reversed! For example, I have 5 < span > elements in a row, if the 4th one is clicked, I want the return to be 1, not 3 (the first one being returned as 0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var elements = $('.elementClass');
var reversedIndex = (elements.length -elements.index(this))+1;
```

Comment: This should actually have `+1` at the end. The last element will have index 4, but the length of the array is 5, giving a result of -1. You probably also want to cache the object from `$('.elementClass')`.

Comment: Sorted! I knew there was something simple and i was making it waaayyyy too complicated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just store your entire list of elements with the class of `elementClass`, and subtract the index from the total number.

```
var elements = $('.elementClass');
elements.click(function() {
    alert(elements.length - elements.index($(this)) - 1);
});
```

Working example here, updated so that the 4th element alerts "1": http://jsfiddle.net/vM3Bb/1/

Comment: See my comment on @RossDargan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
var element = jQuery(this);                
var reverseIndex = element.parent().children().length-(element.index()+1);
```